# detete rows after fetching the data from them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `auditrtailreference` from which I am fetching some data by running the following query

```
SELECT t3.destinationid AS input,
    t1.sourceid AS Raw,
    t1.outtime::TEXT,
    t6.destinationid AS out_file,
    t4.outtime::TEXT AS out_time,
    t1.bytes AS inbytes,
    t6.bytes AS outbyte,
    t5.cdrs AS inputcdrs,
    t6.cdrs AS outputcdrs,
    t6.partial_cdrs,
    t6.duplicate_cdrs,
    t6.discarded_cdrs,
    t6.created_cdrs,
    t6.corrupted_cdrs,
    t6.created_files,
    t6.duplicate_files,
    t6.corrupted_files,
    t6.partial_files,
    t6.discarded_files,
    t6.empty_files
FROM auditrtailreference t1
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t2 ON t2.sourceid = t1.destinationid
    AND t2.event = '80'
    AND t2.innodename LIKE 'SDP%_SFTP'
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t3 ON t3.sourceid = t2.destinationid
    AND t3.event = '68'
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t4 ON t4.sourceid = t3.destinationid
    AND t4.event = '67'
    AND (
        t4.innodename LIKE 'SDP%_Collector'
        OR t4.innodename LIKE 'SDP%_collector'
        )
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t5 ON t5.sourceid = t4.destinationid
    AND t5.event = '73'
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t6 ON t6.destinationid LIKE t3.destinationid || '%'
    AND t6.event = '68'
    AND (
        t6.outnodename LIKE 'SDP%_distributer'
        OR t6.outnodename LIKE 'SDP%_Arch'
        OR t6.outnodename LIKE 'SDP%_distributor'
        OR t6.outnodename LIKE 'SDP%_Distributor'
        OR t6.outnodename LIKE 'SDP%_Distributer'
        )
WHERE t1.event = '67'
    AND t1.innodename LIKE 'SDP%_SFTP'
    AND t3.destinationid LIKE '%'
    AND t1.outtime >= '2014/09/09 00:00'
    AND t1.outtime <= '2014/09/10 19:51'
    AND t3.outnodename LIKE '%init_Dist';
```

Now I need to delete all the rows from which I fetched the valid data (valid data here means that all the columns I have fetched must be not null)

Now why I am doing this is because I am receiving the data in form of files.... to which I am inserting to this tables, Now I am running a daemon in background that fetches the necessary data and Insert into another table.

After this I need to remove all the rows from initial table that I have inserted into the final table

Comment: I am using postgresql database and my daemon is erlang process :)

Comment: I think the readability of this question would go a long way if you cleaned up your sql. formatting is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the primary key in your table (auditrtailreference) and you can create a DELETE from SELECT query

maybe this is example:

```
DELETE FROM auditrtailreference
WHERE ROW_ID IN 
  (select ROW_ID from auditrtailreference... JOIN .... WHERE...)
```

Comment: But you have a t1.sourceid, maybe this could be the unique key for this query.

Comment: No my friend its not unique.....it may be even null......just 1 question can I use ctid in postgres to solve my purpose?

Comment: Is a good idea, with ctid you can identify specific physical record.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy..will try the same & will get back to you